# How to store environment variables with Figaro on a non Heroku server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, figaro-ruby

I have a `Rails 5` app, and I'm trying to store my environment variables on a non Heroku server.

Therefore I created a `config/application.yml` file with my environment variables on the production server.

However, when I try to deploy my Rails app, the deployment fails because the environment variables can't be accessed.

Am I missing something?

Comment: are you using `capistrano` as deployment tool?

Comment: @illusionist, yes I am

Answer (score 0):

> This answer is tested with `Capistrano 3.6.1`

Well, in that case, you would have to make `capistrano` upload your `application.yml` (`database.yml` if its ignored from `git`).

```
# in config/deploy.rb

# Default value for :linked_files is []
append :linked_files, 'config/database.yml', 'config/application.yml'
```

Now write some code to upload the files to the server

```
# lib/capistrano/tasks/uploader.rake
namespace :upload do
  desc 'Upload shared files to the server'
  task :yml_files do
    on roles(:web) do |host|
      fetch(:linked_files).each do |common_file|
        upload! common_file, "#{fetch(:deploy_to)}/shared/#{common_file}"
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Now you need to trigger the above mentioned `capistrano` task just before a very specific event.

```
# config/deploy.rb

before 'deploy:check:linked_files', 'upload:yml_files'
```

This will make sure the necessary environment variables are set before your deployed tries to boot your application in the production server.